# Parse notifications doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, notifications

i'm trying to use parse notification in my iOS app, i followed step by step the guide on the parse.com website but it still doesn't works, here is my app delegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{



    [Parse enableLocalDatastore];

    // Initialize Parse.
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"XXXXXXXXXXXX"
                  clientKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXX"];




    // [Optional] Track statistics around application opens.
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];


    NSLog(@"START");
    // Register for Push Notitications
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);

    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }

       [self grabStoryboard];
    [FBLoginView class];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];


    return YES;
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error.code == 3010) {
        NSLog(@"Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.");
    } else {
        // show some alert or otherwise handle the failure to register.
        NSLog(@"application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error);
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

On parse.com i see that i've 1 registered device, but when i click on "send push" the pushes sent are 0

Answer (score 0):

You should check you App settings on Parse. Go to push notifications and see if you've uploaded the right certificates (Apple Push Certificates). This should solve your problem.

Comment: yes, i uploaded it with the same bundle identifier of my app

Answer (score 0):

add this in the did register for remote notifications section.

```
[currentInstallation setObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"owner"];
```

and where you send your push add this

```
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"owner" containedIn:self.recipients];
```

also if this does not work show me your method where you send your push